# Magento 2 - How to get Addresses collection

Tags: magento2, collection, customer-address, address

In Magento 2, I try to get addresses collection from table 'customer_address_entity', filter by updated_at field.

I know I can get addresses for customer with this :

```
$customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);
$addresses = $customer->getAddresses();
```

I don't want to load every customer, is there a way to get addresses collection like this,
but instead of '_customerFactory' is there a '_addressFactory' method ?:

```
$collection = $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                ->addAttributeToFilter("updated_at", array("gteq" => $start))
                ->addAttributeToFilter("updated_at", array("lteq" => $end))
                ->load();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Customer Address repository - see `Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface::getList()`

You need to use `SearchCriteriaBuilder` with `FilterBuilder` & `FilterGroupBuilder`. Here is an example - but you should add these are dependencies in your construct, of course, not using objectManager.

```
$customerAddressRepository = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface::class);
$filterBuilder = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder::class);
$filterGroupBuilder = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder::class);
$searchCriteriaBuilder = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder::class);

$filter1 = $filterBuilder->setField('updated_at')->setValue($startDate)->setConditionType('gteq')->create();
$filterGroup1 = $filterGroupBuilder->setFilters([$filter1])->create();

$filter2 = $filterBuilder->setField('updated_at')->setValue($endDate)->setConditionType('lteq')->create();
$filterGroup2 = $filterGroupBuilder->setFilters([$filter2])->create();

$searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder->setFilterGroups([$filterGroup1, $filterGroup2])->create();
$addresses = $customerAddressRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();

foreach ($addresses as $address) {
  echo $address->getFirstName().' '.$address->getLastName().'<br>';
  foreach($address->getStreet() as $street) {
    echo $street.'<br>';
  }
  echo $address->getCity().', '.$address->getRegion()->getRegion().', '.$address->getCountryId().'<br><br>';
}
```

You can add more Filters to each FilterGroup - that would be an OR condition.

Each FilterGroup is an AND condition.
See reference for [searching repositories](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/searching-with-repositories.html)

Answer (score 0):

Bernieu2  answer  is  right but If you have customer address ids You can use AddressRepositoryInterface's getById method to  directly  load  customer addresses

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customer,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressInterface,
) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        $this->addressInterface = $addressInterface;
```

}

```
        $billling_address_id = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
        $billling_address = $this->addressInterface->getById($billling_address_id);
        $phone  = $billling_address->getTelephone();
        $postcode  = $billling_address->getPostcode();
        $region  = $billling_address->getRegion()->getRegion();
        $country  = $billling_address->getCountryId();
```